# How to get the count of foreign field in mongodb using $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Collections (this is a sample, not the real data) in 1-m relationship
here is the data for question collection

```
[
    {
        "_id":"question1",
        "text":"test test test test"
    },
    {
        "_id":"question2",
        "text":"test test test test"
    },
    {
        "_id":"question3",
        "text":"test test test test"
    },
    {
        "_id":"question4",
        "text":"test test test test"
    }
]
```

and here is the data for replies collection

```
[
    {
        "_id":'reply1',
        "questionId":"question1",
        "text":"Hello World1"
    },

    {
        "_id":'reply2',
        "questionId":"question1",
        "text":"Hello World1"
    },

    {
        "_id":'reply3',
        "questionId":"question2",
        "text":"Hello World1"
    },

    {
        "_id":'reply4',
        "questionId":"question3",
        "text":"Hello World1"
    },
]
```

when I  use $lookup it join the 2 collections and give me this result

```
[
    {
        "_id":"question1",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":[{...},{...}]
    },
    {
        "_id":"question2",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":[{...}]
    },
    {
        "_id":"question3",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":[{...}]
    },
    {
        "_id":"question4",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":[]
    }
]
```

but I need to get the count of the foreign field instead of array contains the documents I want the result to be like this

```
[
    {
        "_id":"question1",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":2
    },
    {
        "_id":"question2",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":1
    },
    {
        "_id":"question3",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":1
    },
    {
        "_id":"question4",
        "text":"test test test test",
        "totalReplies":0
    }
]
```

is there anyway for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // your current pipeline ($lookup)
    {
        $addFields: { totalReplies: { $size: "$totalReplies" } }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WEdaKkl5Gq3)